# Uncaught Error: failed to require "socket.io" from "root"

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to use the new socket.io 1.0 with NodeJS and on the client side I am seeing this error - 'Uncaught Error: failed to require "socket.io" from "root"'
, it looks to be something wrong with my clientside path, but the path has worked with 0.9.

Edit* This appears to be an issue with socket.io 1.0 and there is a small fix available for this, although I was not able to get it working.  So instead I went back to 0.9.

Comment: This is definitely a real question and a client side error numerous other people are seeing when using socket.io client side.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/socket_io/rLA6Wth59ng - See the first question there